# Creating functions for multiple created elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cgoddard/eceGc/1/

And I was wondering what needed to be done so that each of the three created link will alert a number (i.e. the number it `i` was on at the time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eceGc/2/

```
var selectorObject = document.getElementById('selector');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   (function(i) {
       /* all code here */
   }(i));
}
```

just wrap the body of your loop into a closure (a self-executed anonymous function), passing the current `i` as argument.

The issue with your code happens because when the click event is triggered, the value of `i` has reached the limit inside the loop so you're reading that value.

---

Another way to avoid this behaviour is to ususally move all the code inside the loop in a function and then, call that function inside the loop (always passing the `i` variable as argument)

Comment: Ooh, nifty, didn't think of doing it that way. Cheers